# How to always allow share camera in iceweasel?

Tags: camera, webcam, web-browsers, webrtc

When I visit some online camera call website with webRTC by iceweasel on Raspberry PI 2, it will ask me share camera and microphone.

No meter I select 'Share Selected Devices' or 'Always Share', they work fine.

However if I select 'Always Share', next time I visit this website, it will access camera and/or microphone fails. I must clear 'Site Preferences' and refresh.

How can I force share my camera and microphone without showing the confirming window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I update Iceweasel to v31.8.0 by `apt-get upgrade` .

It was fixed!!